# Google sheet query with importrange and different IF statements

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In order to rather datas of different sheets, I would like to create graphics.
But to do that i want to do a query statement that take others sheets depending on two things.
Here is the formula that i tried to do this but it didn't worked :

```
=IF($D$13="name_1";
    {QUERY(
        IMPORTRANGE("url_1";"sheet_name!range");
        "SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13 WHERE Col1 ='" & $D$10& "'");
        "ERROR"});

IF($D$13="name_2";
    {QUERY(
        IMPORTRANGE("url_2";"sheet_name!range");
        "SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13 WHERE Col1 ='" & $D$10& "'");
        "ERROR")};
```

But this is not working.
I want that, depending on the "name", in the D13 cell, that display the datas the query bellow.
So if it is the "name_1" in the cell D13, that show his datas from his sheet.

| Cell D13 |
| --- |
| Name_1 |

| Cell D10 |
| --- |
| Datas |

That will displays the datas in a table :

| Month | Data 1 | Data 2... | Date 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 12 | 15 | 321 |
| February | 14 | 112 | 45 |

If I choose an other data in the cell D10 or/and in the cell D13 that will display other datas from other Sheet :

| Month | Data 1 | Data 2... | Date 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 2 | 47 | 36 |
| February | 54 | 85 | 7 |

I tried with the IFS statement as well but that worked.
Thx for your help !

Comment: You do not include `D13` in query where condition.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: all sheets are private

Comment: Fixed, you can edit now

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thx mate i will improve it

Answer (score 0):

you can add another `where` with `and` for example like this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url_2"; "sheet_name!range")};
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 
  where Col1 ='"&$D$10&"'
    and Col2 ='"&D$1$3&"'")
```

Comment: The D13 cell is not in the other file, thats why i dont put it in the query where condition